# Java 8 update throws exception

Tags: java

Every time I try to install the downloaded Java 8 runtime environment i get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: illegal IPv4 address
    at java.net.HostPortrange.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLPermission$Authority.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLPermission.parseURI(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLPermission.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLPermission.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.URLtoSocketPermission(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentType(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.isSupportedINSFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.retrieveContentOfPACFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.contructLegacyPACScript_16(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.AbstractAutoProxyHandler.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.SunAutoProxyHandler.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DynamicProxyManager.reset(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.net.proxy.DeployProxySelector.reset(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.initializeExecutionEnvironment(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

I first got this error while trying to update java so I decided to reinstall java however this did not fix my issue.

Comment: Does your company/ISP/govt block websites?

Comment: Looks somewhat similar to https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8139899 -- are you using a proxy to access the web?

Comment: I'm not using a proxy. My government does block some websites. Mostly adult ones, I can access Oracle's websites though if that matters.

Comment: @BedirhanUluçeçen: the presence of `AbstractAutoProxyHandler.retrieveContentOfPACFile` in the stack trace makes me think you *are* actually using a proxy. Possibly one automatically configured via your HDCP server.

Comment: How may I check/disable if I'm using a proxy?

Comment: I have checked my settings for proxies and entered the command "netsh winhttp reset proxy" to make sure. The result was: Current WinHTTP proxy settings: Direct access (no proxy server).

Answer (score 0):

I got same error and most probably company have some restriction. I execute as administrator and my problem was fixed

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34991474)